# jquery slide toggle as a form checkbox

Tags: jquery, css, forms

How would I go about using something like this Jquery Slide toggle as a checkbox in a form?

[JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gnQUe/169/)

Thanks so much in advance. :)

Comment: I want to. But not sure how to configure it to behave like a checkbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go, this example show the checkbox: http://jsfiddle.net/skimberk1/TUPG7/

And in this example, it's hidden: http://jsfiddle.net/skimberk1/KNHu7/

The way it works is that it detects if theres a checkbox directly after the toggle, and if there is, it hides it and checks/unchecks it when you slide the toggle.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Works really well. Anthony Grist's response was just a little less code. ;)

Comment: Yeah, but this better replicates a checkbox. :P

Comment: Yes it does! Changed answer to yours as it answers the question better. Both answers are great though. Thanks to the both of you.

Answer (score 5):

You could map it to a hidden form element that contains a boolean value, and update that value when the slider is toggled.

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnQUe/170/)