# Jquery multiple slide checkbox in a page

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox, slide

I'm using the code from this page http://jsfiddle.net/gnQUe/170/

[jquery slide toggle as a form checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260336/jquery-slide-toggle-as-a-form-checkbox)

how can i use multiple such switches in a single page, if I'm using the same script & css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, put the hidden input in the same `div` as the controls, and give it a `class` instead of an `id`:

```
<div class="slider-frame">
    <span class="slider-button">NO</span>
    <input type="hidden" class="slider-value" value="false">
</div>
```

Then use this jQuery to change it's value:

```
$('.slider-button').toggle(function() {
    $(this).addClass('on').html('YES');
    $(this).next(".slider-value").val(true);
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('on').html('NO');
    $(this).next(".slider-value").val(false);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnQUe/287/)

You'll see in the fiddle I've left the inputs as `text` so you can see the value changing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same div with 'slider-frame' class many times

Please check the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ranganadh/s2TWJ/1/) here

Comment: The problem is that there is only 1 field storing the value of all the checkboxes.

Comment: I think there is no need of hidden elements,
Please check this http://fiddle.jshell.net/ranganadh/sg5WU/show/

Comment: Of course you need hidden elements - how else are you going to pass the selected values back to the server?